# Drupal tagging via tagadelic

Tags: drupal

this module does a good job at creating a tagcloud block - all good here. now id also like to have a page that lists all tags with next to each tag the number of posts that were tagged with this term. all terms are listed ok on http://example.com/?q=tagadelic/list/3 but i dont think tagadelic can add the number of posts per tag?

also, it seems tagadelic can just output one single block "tags in tags". whatever changes i make in the tagadelic configuration is applied to the tagadelic/list/3 url AND to the tagcloud block in the sidebar (the order of tags and number of tag levels)

does what i need require some custom module or are there others around that can achieve this? ive been playing around with Views 2 but cant quite get what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [views_cloud](http://drupal.org/project/views_cloud) for a much more flexible solution.

**Edit:** If you are having trouble with the views module, there is some very good in-browser instructions that come with it, but they require the [advanced_help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module.

Comment: thanks for this, checking it out now. Views is no prob, my favorite drupal module

Comment: I add a view and set "cloud" for Basic Settings > Style.  Then i see a "cloud weight field" drop down but there are no values and this field is required :(

Can this module also output a page that lists all tags +  the number of posts for each tag linked to a page with all posts with this tag? if that makes sense ...

Comment: I have no idea, it's been a while since I used it myself. Now that I look at the last update date, I suppose it's entirely possible it's no longer compatible with the views module.

Comment: its purpose seems to be to output clouds but that "cloud weight field" wont go away. and showing the nbr of posts per tag isnt possible.

Comment: The cloud weight is how big it is. Without a field specifying the weight of each item, the cloud is fairly useless, it's just a list again. On the topic of showing number of posts, it should be possible, but like I said, it's been a long time since I used either drupal or this module

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/term_node_count adds the count of nodes per taxonomy term as an available Views field.

Answer (score 0):

For historical information: 
Tagadelic can add the number of posts per tag, just fine. Assuming your theme is called "red":

```
/**
 * theme function that renders the HTML for the tags
 * @ingroup themable
 */
function red_tagadelic_weighted($terms) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $output .= l($term->name, taxonomy_term_path($term), array('attributes' => array('class' => "tagadelic level$term->weight", 'rel' => 'tag'))) .' ('. $term->count .') ';
  }
  return $output;
}
```